# LWC - Create Copy Button (Closed)

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-button, fields, lightning-button

I use this code to create a button (Lightning Component) on Account object to copy information from Shipping Address to Billing Address but it did not work, can you guys help me to look at my code?

Thanks,
Pam.

JavaScript

````
import { getRecord, updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';
import ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Id';
import BILLING_EMAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Email__c';
import BILLING_PHONE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Phone';
import BILLING_ADDRESS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.BillingAddress';

const FIELDS = [
                 'Account.Id',
                 'Account.Shipping_Phone__c',
                 'Account.Shipping_Email__c',
                 'Account.ShippingAddress',
];

export default class CopyButton extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track account;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.account = data;
        }
    }

    handleOnClick() {
        console.log("handleOnBillingCopy");
        console.log(this.recordId);
        this.copy();
    }

    

    copy() {
        console.log("Copy Billing Information");

        const fields = {};
        fields[ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.account.fields.Id.value;
        fields[BILLING_PHONE_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.account.fields.Shipping_Phone__c.value;
        fields[BILLING_EMAIL_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.account.fields.Shipping_Email__c.value;
        fields[BILLING_ADDRESS_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.account.fields.ShippingAddress.value;

        const recordInput = {fields};

        updateRecord(recordInput)
        .then(() => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: "Success",
                    message: "Your Billing Information Have Been Copied",
                    variant: "Success"
                }),
            );
            this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
        })
        .catch( error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: "Error",
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: "Error"
                }),
            );
        });
    }
}```



HTML
<template>
    <lightning-button label="Copy Shipping Info" title="copyShippingButton" onclick={handleOnClick} class="slds-m-left_small">

    </lightning-button>
</template>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because Address field are compound fields.

The easiest way is to get each address field individually

```
import BILLING_STREET_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.BillingStreet';
import BILLING_CITY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.BillingCity';
...
```

and then copy the corresponding Shipping fields into them (Account.ShippingStreet, Account.ShippingCity ...)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes @LuismaWhatakuai, you are right, I did not notice that part.

Comment: Hi @Luisma, thank you so much! Your solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line of code - `const recordInput = {fields};`
with - `const recordInput = fields;`

And I would suggest you to use flow instead of LWC for this purpose. Always try to solve your problem with a no-code approach. If something cannot be done without code then only you should go with the code approach.

Comment: const recordInput = {fields} is a correct instantiation as fields is an attribute of the recordInput: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_update_record

Comment: Hi @Gaurav Suthar,

Thank you so much for your answer. I noted about Flows.